# iOS App Development - Rules for in app email subscription form?

Tags: ios, iphone

I was wondering if Apple had any rules for integrating an email subscription form into a mobile application where the user can submit their email address to receive updates regarding an app? I searched through the various rules regarding app development for iOS and did not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem at all, since the user knows that they're entering their email address for the newsletter. Now, if you were to prompt the user for their email when the app opens, with no clear indication that they would be subscribing to an email list, then Apple might have a problem.

An example of why this shouldn't be a problem is because of services like OpenFeint, which ask for your email address and sign you up into their service.